# How to access the files uploaded in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, upload

I'm trying to create an upload button using material UI that would allow users to upload many files and then save their path into an array to use later. I'm having trouble understanding where the files get stored once they are uploaded.

I have the following component for an upload button:
Upload.js

```
export default function Upload ({onUpload}) {
return (
    <div >
        <input
            style={{ display: 'none' }}
            id="upload-raw-files"
            multiple
            type="file"
            onChange={onUpload}
        />
        <label htmlFor="upload-raw-files">
            <Button 
            variant="contained"
            component="span"
            size="large"
            className="Upload"
            startIcon={<UploadIcon />}
            sx={{
                
                width: '130px',
                height: '40px',
                background: '#5985F7',
                border: '3px solid #5985F7',
            }}
            >
            Upload
            </Button>
        </label>
        
    </div>
) }
```

This makes the filesystem pop up and we can pick multiple files, but I'm struggling to find a way to retrieve the files selected.
In the parent I call this component like this:

```
import Upload from './Upload.js'
const Form = () => {
    const [filepath, setFilepath] = useState([])

    const handleUpload = (event) => {
        setFilepath(event.target.files)
        console.log(filepath)
    }
    <Upload onUpload={handleUpload}/>
}
```

However this is not printing anything to the console, so I'm confused how I am supposed to have access to the files selected. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> However this is not printing anything to the console

I'm pretty sure it `log`s your initial state value - an empty Array (`[]`) - that is because your function `handleUpload`'s scope knows about `filepath = []` at the time of calling it.

To print the current value you have 2 options:

```
import Upload from "./Upload.js";
const Form = () => {
  const [filepath, setFilepath] = useState([]);
  console.log("filepath is:", filepath); // Option 1

  const handleUpload = (event) => {
    // filepath === []
    setFilepath(event.target.files);
    // filepath === []
    console.log("filepath will be:", event.target.files); // Option 2
  };
  <Upload onUpload={handleUpload} />;
};
```